# How do I retrieve the values for the select2 dropdowns options from the users table?

Tags: javascript, jquery-select2

I want to retrieve the record of the current user for updating process. For both of the select2 dropdowns, the option listings are correct but I am not getting the right values of `role` and `supervisor` as the pre-selected values in each dropdown. What am I missing?

create_users_table.php

```
<?php
use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;
class CreateUsersTable extends Migration {
    public function up() {
        Schema::create('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->id();
            $table->string('name');
            $table->string('role');
            $table->string('supervisor');
        });
    }
    public function down() {Schema::dropIfExists('users')}
}
```

update.blade.php

```
<div><form method="post" action="{{ route('user.update', [$group, $user->id])}}">@csrf
    <div>
        <label for="name">Name</label>
        <div><input id="name" name="name" class="form-control" v-model.trim="$v.user.name.$model"></div>
    </div>
    <div>
        <label for="role">Role</label>
        <div class="custom-select2">
            <select2 ref="role" id="role" name="role" class="form-control" v-model.trim="$v.user.role.$model">
                <option v-for="(opt, index) in role_opt" :selected="opt.role==user.role" :key="opt.role" :value="opt.role">@{{ opt.role }}</option>
            </select2>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div>
        <label for="supervisor">Supervisor</label>
        <div class="custom-select2">
            <select2 ref="supervisor" id="supervisor" name="supervisor" class="form-control" v-model.trim="$v.user.supervisor.$model">
                <option v-for="(user, index) in userList" :selected="user.id == user.name" :key="user.id" :value="user.name">@{{ user.name }}</option>
            </select2>
        </div>
    </div>
</form></div>

<script type="text/javascript">
    var app = new Vue({
         el: '#app',
         data() {
             return {
                user: @json($json_user),
                role_opt: [
                    {role: 'management', name: 'Management'},
                    {role: 'employee', name: 'Employee'}
                ],
                userList: [],
             }
         }
    });
</script>
```

web.php

```
Route::prefix('user')->group(function () {
        Route::get('/', 'UserController@index')->name('user.index');
        Route::get('/{group}/', 'UserController@index_group')->name('user.index.group');
        Route::get('/ajax/list', 'UserController@user_list')->name('data.user.list');
    });
```

User.php

```
<?php
namespace App;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;

class User extends Authenticatable {
    protected $fillable = [
        'name',
        'role',
        'supervisor',
    ];
    public function users() {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\User');
    }
}
```

UserController.php

```
<?php
namespace App\Http\Controllers;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Http\Requests\UserStoreRequest;
use App\Http\Requests\UserUpdateRequest;
use App\User;

class UserController extends Controller {
    
    public function index_group($group) {
        $group_name = '';
        if ($group) {
            switch ($group) {   
                case 'admin':
                    $group_name = 'Admin';
                    break;
                case 'management':
                    $group_name = 'Management';
                    break;
                case 'employee':
                    $group_name = 'Employee';
                    break;
            }
        }
        return view('user.index', compact('group', 'group_name'));
    }

    public function update($group, $id) {
        switch ($group)
        {   
            case 'admin':
                $group_name = 'Admin';
                break;
            case 'management':
                $group_name = 'Management';
                break;
            case 'employee':
                $group_name = 'Employee';
                break;
            default:
                abort(404, 'Unknown group');
                break;
        }
        $user = User::findOrFail($id);
        $json_user = [
            'name' => $user->name,
            'role' => $user->role,
            'supervisor' => $user->supervisor,
        ];
        return view('user.update', compact('group','group_name','user', 'json_user'));
    }

    public function user_list() {
        $users = User::get();
        $data = [];
        $data = $users->map(function($item, $index) {
            return [
                "name" => $item->name,
                "role" => $item->role,
                "supervisor" => $item->supervisor,
            ];
        });
        return $data;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe it could be a case-sensitive issue.

If you change the role_opt[].role to begin with capital letter

```
role_opt: [
  {role: 'Management', name: 'Management'},
  {role: 'Employee', name: 'Employee'}
],
```

Comment: Pardon, Sir @Joseph Troy. I'm afraid it is not. I've tried that, but it seems that it is not our concern here.

Comment: OK, I added a new answer which hopefully helps out.  If not, then I'm sorry I couldn't be of any help. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

OK, if it's not a case sensitive issue, then I believe it has something to do with the `<select2 >` tag.  It is not a standard HTML tag.. and may not understand how to set itself to a 'selected' option.  It depends on how you defined the tag.

I think the easiest thing to try for now is change it from `<select2>` to `<select>`  It should set the default values.  If it works, then there is something not quite right with the select2.  If it *doesn't* work, then I would inspect the user object `$user = User::findOrFail($id);` to ensure everything is exactly as expected.